# Good websites for map-lovers?

Tags: cartography

I often visit [strange-maps](http://bigthink.com/blogs/strange-maps), [cool-maps](http://cool-maps.blogspot.com/), [makingmaps](http://makingmaps.net/) and [hipkiss.org](http://www.hipkiss.org/data/maps.html).

Do you know of other good websites for map-lovers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

Websites:

- [cartastrophe](http://cartastrophe.wordpress.com/)
- [cartophile](http://cartophile.tumblr.com/)

David Rumsey Map Collection
http://www.davidrumsey.com/

Map Gallery
http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showforum=14

Ancient World Mapping Center
http://www.unc.edu/awmc/mapsforstudents.html

Huge Resource - Berkeley Map Collection
http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/EART/MapCollections.html

These are good for OpenStreetMap-lovers:

- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category:Featured_images
- http://bestofosm.org/

The [International Cartographic Association](http://icaci.org/) website has a section with some [beautiful maps selected every month](http://icaci.org/map-of-the-month).

Answer (score 4):

- OpenStreetMap (http://openstreetmap.org)
- MapBox (http://mapbox.com/) - for creating custom maps in the cloud using OpenStreetMap and other data sources

For historic maps:

- Perry-Castañeda Library Map Collection at University of Texas (http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/)
- Library of Congress map collection (http://lcweb2.loc.gov/ammem/gmdhtml/gmdhome.html)

Answer (score 4):

Some more:

- http://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/
- http://www.cartogrammar.com/portfolio.html
- http://timwallace.wordpress.com/page/2/
- http://indiemaps.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 3):

I am maintaining a map site, all my own creations. Pretty in its infancy, but I hope you guys would like it: http://mapsnmaps.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Mapillary](https://www.mapillary.com) - Crowd sourced street level photography that you can contribute to with using a smartphone or action camera. Uses OSM as a base map.

Answer (score 2):

[Lithuanianmaps.com](http://Lithuanianmaps.com) - Here are, believe it or not, over 1,500 unique maps of the area covered by the historic, c17th century, Lithuanian region, which includes Estonia, Latvia, Lithuania, Belarus, Eastern Poland, Kaliningrad Oblast and Ukraine.