# Seeking examples of Creative Cartography?

Tags: cartography

I am looking for some examples of creative cartographic output. I am planning for something like a mixture of cartography, graphic design and spatial information. The output will be initially in hardcopy, maybe poster size maps. These maps are reuired to be very unconvetional, uncommon but appleanig. I am not bothered about map scale, projection or other technical details, since my target audience will be mostly laymen in mapping. This could be considered as an idea of InfoGraphics, with a spatial sauce!

For example what I have in my mind is

1. A map for "Around the World in Eighty Days" by Jules Verne. This
   will be a poster size map, with world boundary and trip route
   alongwith some images/ photographs/ descriptions at major breaks.
2. Another could be the use of beautifull and informativs symbols in
       pollution maps (Elements of cartography, H. Robinson), where all the
       indicators are shown as a combination of parts of human face. eg.
       size of ear for sound pollution, color of mose for air
       pollution(from red to yellow), the curve of mouth for water
       pollution and etc.
3. Or even a map of Europe made out of clothes. You can see it
   [here](http://corrietteschoenaerts.com/maps/1).

I am not looking for webmaps or historical maps or maps of very specialized theme that requires special understanding of maps.

Comment: you should look at this question ([Examples of Beautiful Maps](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps)) which had been asked before...i think it is what you want.. i hope it helps you...

Comment: As I have just edited, I am not looking for webmaps or historical maps or maps of very specialized theme that requires special understanding of maps. I have gone through most of the answers. But most of these maps are either historical maps or very specialized map. I need more general theme maps with unconventional representation. Perhaps a population density map...

Comment: You might want to browse through [**cartophile**](http://cartophile.tumblr.com/) blog for some inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may screen the websites listed at [Good websites for map-lovers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/good-websites-for-map-lovers) and also have a look at [flowingdata](http://flowingdata.com/). I love [stamen](http://maps.stamen.com/) maps:

[image: stamen]

Answer (score -2):

I have just posted on my blog (which usually deals in parody-songs) a collection of unsophisticated maps dealing with the US election process (this one, or perhaps any other) from the standpoint of ANAGRAMS of the names of the major parties D-E-M-O-C-R-A-T-S and R-E-P-U-B-L-I-C-A-N-S. As I am a Canadian national, I have written an even quirkier add-on dealing with potential Canadian involvement. 
The purpose of all of this is sheer nonsense, an end which pervades the other works published on the blog. A few prior posts on the blog also deal with geographically based anagrams, sung to the tune, "I've Been Everywhere". A song to encompass the quirky ideas for the present work is projected, but is still a work-in-progress. If this suits some other purpose, enjoy (but please provide feedback)! 
Giorgio's Ukable Parodies   www.ukableparodies.blogspot.com